Workflow for macOS Simulator screen recording to GIF while showing the device frame
Objective: Make some (dozens-hundreds) of 3-5 second lightweight gifs with a device frame and without the Simulator floating container above it the frame. Either with clean shadows (no cropping them) or simply having no shadows at all. Is there a cleaner way to automate this without having to dig into Photoshop timelines?
iPhone simulator with shadows
Sadly, Apple does not have a setting to save the screen recording with the frame, nor enable/disable the shadows on the OS side. I've tried some gitHub projects but they only seem to work on older Apple operating system. I'm currently on Sonoma 14.1.1. If I can disable the OS shadow then a screen recording as a MOV would be quicker to batch processing to GIFs. Or if can hide the top container that states the Device/iOS version Home/Camera/Rotate container that would also make it easier... Suggestions?
Simulator save as animated GIF
Saved GIF doesn't have frame

I don’t have great solution here: Shadows in screen snapshots work great, but are problematic in GIFs (banding, distracting changes frame-by-frame, etc.). Worse, macOS doesn’t have a feature to just turn off shadows in the macOS desktop, either, so recording portion of screen doesn’t work quite right either. Changing wallpaper to solid black at least makes it so you cannot see the shadows that are there. I use CleanShotX for screen snapshots, so at least with that, once you set up the screen recording (with snapping bounds to edges of simulator), I can at least capture consistently sized GIFs.
